# Using comparator in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections, comparator

I'm new to kotlin, how to compare objects using `Collections`

```js
Collections.sort(list,myCustomComparator)
```

How can we write a `MyCustomComparator` method in kotlin?

```js
private final Comparator<CustomObject> myCustomComparator = (a, b) -> {
        if (a == null && b == null) {
            return 0;
        } else if (a == null) {
            return -1;
        } else if (b == null) {
            return 1;
        } 
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considering the @Alexander answer, the code can be written as

```js
private val MyCustomComparator = Comparator<MyObject> { a, b ->
        when {
            a == null && b == null -> return@Comparator 0
            a == null -> return@Comparator -1
            b == null -> return@Comparator 1
          
            else -> return@Comparator 0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

This can be done almost the same way as in Java:

```
private val myCustomComparator =  Comparator<CustomObject> { a, b ->
    when {
        (a == null && b == null) -> 0
        (a == null) -> -1
        else -> 1
    }
}
```

`if else if else ...` was replaced by a single Kotlin `when` in order make the code better readable.

In Kotlin sorting a list using a `Comparator` can also be written like this:

```
val customObjects = listOf(CustomObject(), CustomObject())
customObjects.sortedWith(myCustomComparator)
```

Answer (score 3):

As per other answers, a fairly direct translation lets you sort a list with e.g.:

```
fun myCustomComparator() = Comparator<CustomObject>{ a, b ->
    when {
        (a == null && b == null) -> 0
        (a == null) -> -1
        else -> 1
    }
}
```

Now, there's nothing in here that depends upon your `CustomObject`.  So it's trivial to make it generic, so it can handle any type:

```
fun <T> nullsFirstComparator() = Comparator<T>{ a, b ->
    when {
        (a == null && b == null) -> 0
        (a == null) -> -1
        else -> 1
    }
}
```

However, there are some underlying problems here.

The main one is that **it's inconsistent**.  The general contract for a `Comparator` is spelled out in the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-):

> The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all x and y

(Unfortunately the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparator/compare.html) don't mention any of this.  It's a real shame they're not up to the standard of the Java ones.)

However, the comparator above doesn't do this; if a and b are non-null, then `compare(a, b)` and `compare(b, a)` are both 1!

This is likely to lead to problems; for example, depending how a sort() method is coded, it might leave the list unsorted, or never finish.  Or if you use it for a sorted map, the map might fail to return some of its values, or never finish.

This can be fixed by adding a fourth case:

```
fun <T> nullsFirstComparator() = Comparator<T>{ a, b ->
    when {
        (a == null && b == null) -> 0
        (a == null) -> -1
        (b == null) -> 1
        else -> 0
    }
}
```

The comparator is now consistent; null values always come before non-null ones.

But it still has an undesirable feature: **all non-null values are now treated as equivalent**, and can't be sorted within themselves.  There's no way to fix this in general, as Kotlin doesn't know how to compare the order of two arbitrary objects.  But there are two ways you could tell it how.

One way is to restrict it to objects that have a natural order, i.e. which implement the [`Comparable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/index.html) interface.  (Once again, the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) explain this far better.)

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> nullsFirstComparator() = Comparator<T>{ a, b ->
    when {
        (a == null && b == null) -> 0
        (a == null) -> -1
        (b == null) -> 1
        else -> a.compareTo(b)
    }
}
```

However, you can simplify if you **use the standard library** [`kotlin.comparisons.compareValues()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-values.html) function:

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> nullsFirstComparator()
    = Comparator<T>{ a, b -> compareValues(a, b) }
```

The other is to provide an ordering yourself — which you do by providing *another* `Comparator` to handle the non-null comparisons:

```
fun <T> nullsFirstComparator(comparator: Comparator<T>) = Comparator<T>{ a, b ->
    when {
        (a == null && b == null) -> 0
        (a == null) -> -1
        (b == null) -> 1
        else -> c.compare(a, b)
    }
}
```

But you don't need to write that yourself, because **that's already in the Kotlin standard library**, as [`kotlin.comparisons.nullsFirst()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/nulls-first.html)!

Comment: +1 for not only discussing the actual question but pointing out the basic requirements for Comparable and including Kotlin std lib.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to sort collections in Kotlin - you can use extension function `sortedWith` like this:

```
list.sortedWith(Comparator { s1, s2 ->
    when {
        s1 == null && s2 == null -> 0
        s1 == null -> -1
        else -> 1
    }
})
```

But remember, this will return **a copy** of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) with lambda (because `Comparator` is a Java interface and Kotlin will allow you to do so) or an anonymous class object.

With lambda it will look like this:

```
val customComparator = Comparator<CustomObject> { a, b ->
    if (a == null && b == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (a == null) {
        return -1;
    } else if (b == null) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And anonymous class version:

```
val customComparator = object: Comparator<CustomObject> {
    override fun compare(a: CustomObject, b: CustomObject): Int {
        if (a == null && b == null) {
            return 0;
        } else if (a == null) {
            return -1;
        } else if (b == null) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```