# How do I sort a list of objects in a very specific order according to the name of the obects?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to sort a list called findLoot

And basically I want to do a sort on this list, this list contains class objects, items if you will. And they have all names which can be called with a class method called .name() which returns their name as a string.

I have a very specific order I want these items to be sorted by based on their name, that is not in like an alphabetical order or anything but rather based on my own custom order which I have in this list:

```
    private val mappingOfLootList = listOf("Draconic visage", "Onyx bolt tips", "Coins", "Nature rune", "Shield left half", "Dragon med helm",
            "Rune 2h sword", "Dragon spear", "Rune kiteshield", "Rune battleaxe", "Rune sq shield", "Rune full helm", "Rune longsword",
            "Rune spear", "Rune med helm", "Adamant platebody", "Lava battlestaff", "Rune axe", "Adamant 2h sword", "Fire orb", "Runite bar",
            "Dragonstone", "Tooth half of key", "Loop half of key", "Grimy ranarr weed", "Rune javelin", "Blood rune", "Runite bolts", "Rune dart",
            "Death rune", "Law rune", "Silver ore", "Lava dragon bones", "Black dragonhide", "Rune arrow", "Grimy avantoe", "Grimy kwuarm",
            "Grimy cadantine", "Uncut diamond", "Adamantite bar", "Rune knife", "Grimy lantadyme", "Grimy dwarf weed", "Fire talisman")
```

Basically wht I want to do is something like(not actual working code just trying to show what I want to achieve):

```
findLoot.sortByCustomOrder {
    if (mappingOfLootList.getIndexOf(it.name() == 0)
         putTheseItemsInTheFrontOfTheList()
    else if (mappingOfLootList.getIndexOf(it.name() == 1)
         putTheseItemsBehindTheItemsInFrontOfTheList()
}
```

Any help is appriciated

Tried to do sort() and sortBy() but that did not get me far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using comparator in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449443/using-comparator-in-kotlin)

Comment: You need to provide more details on what "Tried to do ... sortBy() but that did not get me far" means.  `sortBy` is likely your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do

```
val result = list.sortedBy { mappingOfLootList.indexOf(it.name()) }
```

Note that when the name is not in the list it will be in front of the list.

Full working example:

```
fun main() {
    val mappingOfLootList = listOf("Draconic visage", "Onyx bolt tips", "Coins", "Nature rune", "Shield left half", "Dragon med helm",
        "Rune 2h sword", "Dragon spear", "Rune kiteshield", "Rune battleaxe", "Rune sq shield", "Rune full helm", "Rune longsword",
        "Rune spear", "Rune med helm", "Adamant platebody", "Lava battlestaff", "Rune axe", "Adamant 2h sword", "Fire orb", "Runite bar",
        "Dragonstone", "Tooth half of key", "Loop half of key", "Grimy ranarr weed", "Rune javelin", "Blood rune", "Runite bolts", "Rune dart",
        "Death rune", "Law rune", "Silver ore", "Lava dragon bones", "Black dragonhide", "Rune arrow", "Grimy avantoe", "Grimy kwuarm",
        "Grimy cadantine", "Uncut diamond", "Adamantite bar", "Rune knife", "Grimy lantadyme", "Grimy dwarf weed", "Fire talisman")

    val list = listOf(
        A("Dragon spear"),
        A("Rune knife"),
        A("Rune javelin"),
        A("Something not in the list"),
        A("Draconic visage")
    )
    val result = list.sortedBy { mappingOfLootList.indexOf(it.name()) }

    println(result)
    // [A(name=Something not in the list), A(name=Draconic visage), A(name=Dragon spear), A(name=Rune javelin), A(name=Rune knife)]

}

data class A(val name: String) {
    fun name() = name
}
```

Comment: Please note this solution is not ideal performance-wise. To check the position of an item we need to iterate over the name list. We can easily improve it by first creating a map name->order: `val nameToOrder = mappingOfLootList.withIndex().associate { it.value to it.index }`. Then we use it like this: `list.sortedBy { nameToOrder[it.name()] }`.

Comment: Could I do something like this then? To have it just in 1 list: `
private val lootPriorityOrderList = listOf("Draconic visage", "Onyx bolt tips", "Coins", "Nature rune", "Shield left half" etc...).withIndex().associate { it.value to it.index }
`

Comment: Yes, if you don't need the initial list, you can skip it at all. Please note this not a list anymore, but a map.